# Rounding a list of floats into integers in Python

Tags: python, list, rounding

I have a list of numbers which I need to round into integers before I continue using the list. Example source list:

```
[25.0, 193.0, 281.75, 87.5, 80.5, 449.75, 306.25, 281.75, 87.5, 675.5,986.125, 306.25, 281.75]
```

What would I do to save this list with all of the numbers rounded to an integer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply use [`round`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_round.htm) function for all list members with list comprehension :

```
myList = [round(x) for x in myList]

myList # [25, 193, 282, 88, 80, 450, 306, 282, 88, 676, 986, 306, 282]
```

If you want [`round`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_round.htm) with certain presicion `n` use [`round(x,n)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_round.htm):

Answer (score 13):

You could use the built-in function [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) with a list comprehension:

```
newlist = [round(x) for x in list]
```

You could also use the built-in function [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
newlist = list(map(round, list))
```

I wouldn't recommend `list` as a name, though, because you are shadowing the built-in type.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a list conversion on your second method?

Comment: @muyustan: You're right. At the time I wrote this answer, I was mostly using Python 2, where `map` returns a list already, but yeah, that's changed.

Answer (score 4):

If you would set the number of significant digits you could do

```
new_list = list(map(lambda x: round(x,precision),old_list))
```

Furthermore, if you had a list of list you could do

```
new_list = [list(map(lambda x: round(x,precision),old_l)) for old_l in old_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) function.

You can set how many digits to [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round).

```
>>> floats = [25.0, 193.0, 281.75, 87.5, 80.5, 449.75, 306.25, 281.75, 87.5, 675.5,986.125, 306.25, 281.75]
>>> rounded = map(round, floats)
>>> print rounded
[25.0, 193.0, 282.0, 88.0, 80.0, 450.0, 306.0, 282.0, 88.0, 676.0, 986.0, 306.0, 282.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's built in `round` function.

```
l = [25.0, 193.0, 281.75, 87.5, 80.5, 449.75, 306.25, 281.75, 87.5, 675.5,986.125, 306.25, 281.75]

list = [round(x) for x in l]

print(list)
```

The output is:

```
[25, 193, 282, 88, 80, 450, 306, 282, 88, 676, 986, 306, 282]
```

Answer (score 2):

NumPy is great for handling arrays like this.
Simply `np.around(list)` or `np.round(list)` works.

Comment: Possibly also helpful to others reading on this topic: `np.rint`

Answer (score 1):

Updating this for python3 since other answers leverage python2's `map`, which returns a `list`, where python3's `map` returns an iterator. You can have the `list` function consume your `map` object:

```py
l = [25.0, 193.0, 281.75, 87.5, 80.5, 449.75, 306.25, 281.75, 87.5, 675.5,986.125, 306.25, 281.75]

list(map(round, l))
[25, 193, 282, 88, 80, 450, 306, 282, 88, 676, 986, 306, 282]
```

To use `round` in this way for a specific `n`, you'll want to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```py
from functools import partial

n = 3
n_round = partial(round, ndigits=3)

n_round(123.4678)
123.468

new_list = list(map(n_round, list_of_floats))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original list of floats is in a numpy array you can use [numpy.rint()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rint.html). Somewhat annoyingly, although it rounds floating point values to the nearest integer, it still leaves them as floats, so you also have to cast them to ints afterwards. Example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2.0, -1.6, -1.2,  0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.45, 2.55, 1.8])
rounded = np.rint(x).astype(int)

# If you want to convert the array back into a regular Python list:
print(rounded.tolist())  # [2, -2, -1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
```